# ¿Cómo puedo adjuntar archivos .txt o .edi en sql server?

Tags: sql, tsql

Quiero adjuntar un archivo `.edi` y un `.txt` pero desde `sql`, no se guardara en ninguna tabla, solo necesito el archivo para enviarlo por correo, ya tengo un `SP` para enviar correos, solo necesito como adjuntar archivos.

Comment: Hola @YoMismo. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! ¿Podrías agregar el código que tenés hasta ahora? Quizás te sea útil realizar el [tour] y leer [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar:

```
EXEC sp_send_dbmail 
  @profile_name='PerfilCorreo',
  @recipients='destinatario@gmail.com',
  @subject='Archivo EDI',
  @body='Envio el archivo de pedidos.',
  @file_attachments='F:\EDI\delfor.xml'
```

[Aquí](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlagent/2010/11/10/sql-database-mail-send-emails-with-attachment/) te dejo el enlace a la página de Microsoft.

Y un articulo en [CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/tips/846204/how-to-send-mail-using-sql-server-part) donde muestra como configurar SQL y enviar el correo.